# PHP include path sub-folder files not included

Tags: php

I have a site where the PHP include path is /usr/share/php
Within this path I have a sub-folder containing some utility files, e.g. /usr/share/php/utils. my_session.php is one of these utility files.

My application calls

```
require ("my_session.php");
```

and this works even though the file is actually within the utils folder.

I am trying to replicate this site in another installation and I am getting the error:

```
Failed opening required 'my_session.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php)
```

My question is:

Should the php include path also include files in sub-folders in the include path?
This appears to be the case on my original site and I don't know why the behaviour seems to be different on the second site.

Comment: no, subfolders are generally not included. did you use `require ("utils/my_session.php");` in your original project?

Comment: Nope, that's the weird thing. I need to look at it again. I am missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to PHP documentation when you try to include a file, only paths listed in the include_path directive are checked. PHP is not supposed to check their subfolders.

Comment: The include for the sub-folder was indeed in the php.ini, but only for apache2. I had checked using `php -i` on the command line but this uses a different ini file.

Comment: Unfortunately sometimes the server configuration is set in a such way  that command line execution of php and apache module are using different php.ini files. I had such problems in the past and I know this is very tricky and hard to catch. Happy to hear that you solved it. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that this fails because you are using a *relative* path for the `require`.

Your `include_path` is defined as `.:/usr/share/php`. That means only two folders will be checked when `require('my_session.php')` gets executed:

- the current path
- the folder `/usr/share/php`

I don't know your folder structure, so let's just imagine one:

```
my_project
- app
-- index.php
- lib
-- my_session.php
```

Now, if `my_project/app/index.php` tries to `require('my_session.php')` this will **fail**, because the current folder at the time executing the `require` is `my_project/app/` and there is no file entry of `my_session.php` relative to `my_project/app/` (it's relative to `my_project/lib/` instead).

Long story short: Try to to use an **absolute** path instead of your relative one, e.g.

```
require('/var/www/html/my_project/lib/my_session.php');
```

---

<sub>Edit: removed *and its subfolders*, which was wrong. Too much __autoload in my brain^^</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

Add `/usr/share/php/utils` to your include_path.

or

Include your file with `require ("utils/my_session.php");`